# Ms Access and PDF as part of report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to embed PDF ( which are receipt of the customers ), to be embedded as image in report  , this could be more then one.

This should be shown as image not PDF icon  on the report because we want to send this to customer.

Please let me know if this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do this.

Just use an unbound object frame, type: Adobe Acrobat Document, and select your PDF.

Note that both you and the client will need an appropriate PDF reader to be able to view the PDF (Adobe Acrobat DC will do).

Comment: Will it be shown as PDF icon ? I need like thumbnail picture instead of just seeing it as PDF icon.

Comment: You were clear about that... I wouldn't answer if it didn't work

Comment: Thanks this answer my question, but one more thing I would like to know is that can we create this unbound object frame object on fly and can have more then one pdf embedded in single page ? and also the size ( height & width ) of the frame should be match to the content of the PDF )

Comment: That's three questions in one, and some requiring pretty sophisticated code to answer. Ask them in separate questions if you need them answered, but note that for these kinds of questions, research and an attempt is expected.